# Carbon formatLocalized returns strange characters

Tags: laravel, localization, php-carbon

I'm using Carbon in Laravel to generate localized date labels in my project.

In my controller I use following code to generate the labels:

```
$today = Carbon::now();

    $labels[] = [
        'date' => $today->format('Y-m-d'),
        'label' => ('Dziś ('.$today->formatLocalized('%a, %e %b').')')
    ];
    $labels[] = [
        'date' => (clone $today )->addDays(1)->format('Y-m-d'),
        'label' => 'Jutro ('.(clone $today)->addDays(1)->formatLocalized('%a, %e %b').')'
    ];
    $labels[] = [
        'date' => (clone $today )->addDays(2)->format('Y-m-d'),
        'label' => (clone $today)->addDays(2)->formatLocalized('%a, %e %b')
    ];
    $labels[] = [
        'date' => (clone $today )->addDays(3)->format('Y-m-d'),
        'label' => (clone $today)->addDays(3)->formatLocalized('%a, %e %b')
    ];
    $labels[] = [
        'date' => (clone $today )->addDays(4)->format('Y-m-d'),
        'label' => (clone $today)->addDays(4)->formatLocalized('%a, %e %b')
    ];
```

And it works OK until there is any language-specific diacrytic sign. If I output the `$labels` with `dd(...)` this is what I get:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => "2017-04-27"
    "label" => "Dziś (czw, 27 kwi)"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => "2017-04-28"
    "label" => b"Jutro (pi±, 28 kwi)"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => "2017-04-29"
    "label" => "sob, 29 kwi"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => "2017-04-30"
    "label" => "nie, 30 kwi"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => "2017-05-01"
    "label" => "pon,  1 maj"
  ]
]
```

Notice strange label for second item:

```
"label" => b"Jutro (pi±, 28 kwi)"
```

correct label should be: `"Jutro (pią, 29 kwi)"`.

Of course labels like that do not output correctly in Blade.

What is wrong? Is it something with coding or maybe I'm using the `formatLocalized` method wrong?

FYI: I have set locales in `boot()` method of my `AppServiceProvider`:

```
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pl_PL');
    \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('pl');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this issue is probably related to utf-8 encoding the polish language requires. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50655610/5848950) to a similar problem.

TL;DR

When using the `setLocale` function use the utf-8 version of locale - `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pl_PL.UTF-8');`