# Bad characters in utf-8 Carbon formatLocalized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I know there is much about this, but it doesn't work, I have the language installed.

```
locale -a | grep es
 es_ES
 es_ES.ISO8859-1
 es_ES.ISO8859-15
 es_ES.UTF-8
```

I have set to utf-8

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setUtf8(true);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
$game_date = $date->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y %H %M %p');
```

I have the utf-8 tag in my html

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

but I am still getting the wrong characters.

> "sÃ¡bado" - "miÃ©rcoles"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to use the `sk_SK.UTF-8` locale. What helped me to solve the problem was to remove the `\Carbon\Carbon::setUtf8(true);` portion of the code.

But why does it work like this? Firstly the Carbon documentation regarding the setUtf8 function says this:

> Some languages require utf8 encoding to be printed (locale packages that does not ends with .UTF8 mainly). In this case you can use the static method Carbon::setUtf8() to encode the result of the formatLocalized() call to the utf8 charset.

Upon examining the source code for Carbon the `formatLocalized()` function calls `utf8_encode()` function from the PHP library if we previously set the variable utf8 to true with the already mentioned `Carbon::setUtf8(true)`.
[Carbon source on GitHub](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php#L1638)

```
return static::$utf8 ? utf8_encode($formatted) : $formatted;
```

Because your locale is already configured to use the UTF-8 standard the further php encoding messes the formatted string up.

I figured that if you want to use Carbon to format your strings to utf8 you must first get rid of the UTF-8 encoding when setting your locale with `setLocale()`. However, I would just stick to removing the Carbon function and using the proper locale.

TL;DR

Use correct locale with UTF-8 encoding e.g. `es_ES.UTF-8` or use try to use locale without the UTF-8 encoding and rely on `\Carbon\Carbon::setUtf8(true);` and `utf8_encode()` function. I suggest the first option. Hope this helped :)

Comment: I was looking for this answer. All the info I found was related to the database but I wasn't using it and I knew it had to do with the library. THANK YOU SO MUCH.